# How to save connection via Bluetooth on configuration changes?

Tags: android, sockets, android-fragments, bluetooth

I have a `Fragment` where I got a reference to `BluetoothConnection` class. In `BluetoothConnection` I handle all things which are necessary for connection via other Bluetooth device. All working fine but when I rotate my device connection disappeared. So how to save connection on configuration changes? I read that with fragments works `setRetainInstance(true)` method but it only skip `onCreate` method. I know I could move all `BluetoothConnection` into `Service` but I don't think this is good solution. Here's my code:

```
private BluetoothConnection connection = null;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

        //setRetainInstance(true);

        adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        // If the adapter is null, then Bluetooth is not supported
        if (adapter == null) {
            FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            activity.finish();
        }
        bindService();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // If BT is not on, request that it be enabled.
        // setupChat() will then be called during onActivityResult
        if (!adapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            // Otherwise, setup the chat session
        } else if (connection == null) {
            setupChat();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
    }
 private void setupChat() {
        if(!isConnected){
            button.setEnabled(false);
        }

        command = new CommandFormatter();
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean turnOn = ((ToggleButton) v).isChecked();
                if (isConnected) {
                    if (turnOn) {
                        formatCommand("On");
                        sendCommand(command.generateXML());
                    } else {
                        formatCommand("Off");
                        sendCommand(command.generateXML());
                        //isConnected = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        // Initialize the BluetoothChatService to perform bluetooth connections
        connection = new BluetoothConnection(handler);
    }
```